# Proving inequality involving derivatives with Taylor polinomials.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I'm working with some exercises about calculus and I'm stuck with one of them. I think that I'm near to solve it, but I don't know how to proceed. The exercise is

> Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a twice differentiable function over $[0,1]$ such that $f(0)=f'(0)=f'(1)=0$ and $f(1)=1$. Prove, using Taylor polinomials, that if $f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\geq \frac{1}{2}$ then there exist $x_1\in\left(0,\frac{1}{2} \right)$ such that $f''(x_1)\geq 4$ and if $f\left(\frac{1}{2} \right)\leq\frac{1}{2}$, then there exist $x_2\in \left(\frac{1}{2},1\right)$ such that $f''(x_2)\leq -4$.

First, we suposse that $f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\geq \frac{1}{2}$ (I think that the another case when $f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\leq \frac{1}{2}$ is analogous). By contradiction, suposse that for all $x\in\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$ holds $f''(x)<4$. By the fact that $f$ is twice differentiable, we can take its first degree Taylor polonimial centered at $x=0$. Then $f(x)=P_{1,f,0}(x)+R_{1,f,0}(x)$ where $R_{1,f,0}(x)$ is the remainder at $x=0$. But by hypothesis $f(0)=f'(0)=0$. Thus $P_{1,f,0}(x)=0$ and then $f(x)=R_{1,f,0}(x)$. By the Lagrange theorem for the remainder, then $$f(1)=\dfrac{f''(c_1)}{2!}=1$$for some $c_1$ between $0$ and $1$. By the same argument $$f\left(\frac{1}{2} \right)=\dfrac{f''(c_2)}{2!}\geq \frac{1}{2}$$for some $c_2$ between $0$ and $1$. Thus $f''(c_2)\geq 1$. But, from here, I don't know how to derive a contradiction or how to going on. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taylor's expansion around $0$:
$$f(x)=f(0)+xf^\prime(0)+\frac{x^2}2 f^{\prime\prime}(c_x)=\frac{x^2}2 f^{\prime\prime}(c_x)\tag{1}$$
for all $x\in [0,\frac 1 2]$ and some $c_x\in (0, x)\subset (0,\frac 1 2)$

Suppose that $f^{\prime\prime}(u)<4$ for all $u\in (0,\frac 1 2)$. Then, using $(1)$, we obtain that for all $x\in[0,\frac 1 2]$, $f(x) < \frac{\left(\frac 1 2\right)^2} 2 4 = \frac 1 2$ (remember that $c_x\in(0,\frac 1 2))$. Evaluate at $x=\frac 1 2$ and obtain $f(\frac 1 2)<\frac 1 2$.

For the other case: A similar reasoning should be applied by using a Taylor expansion around 1.

Comment: When you say that $f(x)<\dfrac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}}{2} 4=\dfrac{1}{2}$ holds, you are asuming  that $x\in\left( 0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$. Then, the inequality is invalid when $x=\frac{1}{2}$. Why we can evaluate that inequality in $x=\frac{1}{2}$. We don't know what is the order relation between $f''\left( \frac{1}{2}\right)$ and $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: And the same for the another case.

Comment: You are correct, I was a bit careless. I've edited my answer. Please take a look.

Comment: Looks good for me. Only one remark: by the Lagrange remainder theorem, for example, in the first case, $f(x)=\dfrac{f''(c_x)}{2!}x^{2}$. What form of the remainder are you using? I use the Lagrange form in your proof and your argument works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: OK, I'm sorry, I was a bit confused. I fixed my Taylor expansion. Should look fine now.

Comment: Yes. It's perfect now. Thanks!